# Hypertable works with Hadoop 2.x?

Tags: hadoop, hypertable

I want to know if I can install Hypertable on top of Hadoop 2.3.0(or 2.2.0). I do not want to use Cloudera for now, because I am new to Hadoop, and just want to learn one thing for now.

Comment: What do you mean? Reading from Hypertable and feed it to Hadoop job? or writing Mapreduce output to Hypertable?

Comment: It's nothing to do with Mapreduce or Hadoop job. Just want to install hypertable on top of HDFS 2.x.

Comment: Ok then, edit your question because it is not clear.